# Raspbian / Debian Networkmanager not working as access point (mode = ap)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-based

I'm trying to build an access point / hotspot with a Raspberry Pi, a wifi dongle and NetworkManager. I know that I can achieve this by just working with hostapd, dnsmasq and ifupdown - I even had it working with this. But I would like to use NetworkManager, as there is a nice Lib I can use to toggle the connections with Python. When reading about Network Manager it says that there are 3 kind of "modes" I can use. "Infrastructure", "ap" and "adhoc" - Infrastracture and "adhoc" are working, but not the ap one, which I need. This is what the Logs are giving me.

```
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile: updating /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot_safe_save_075806
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile:     error: File did not exist or was not a regular file
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile: updating /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot_safe_save_075806
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile:     error: File did not exist or was not a regular file
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile: removed /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot.
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile: updating /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile:     error: invalid or missing connection property 'mode'
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile: updating /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
Jun 22 00:08:09 raspberrypi NetworkManager[2760]:    keyfile:     error: invalid or missing connection property 'mode'
```

What am I doing wrong? I Read that it could be that i need to recompile wpasupplicant - but with this i got some trouble. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you get it working? Otherwise, could it be related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247866/create-a-new-hotspot-with-just-terminal-and-networkmanager-nmcli ?

Comment: I got AP mode to work, you might want to try if my answer to the question I linked in the comment above helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was trying to do this with an Raspbian (Debian) Wheezy Image, which has an older NetworkManager. With the Jessie Image everything is working like a breeze now.
I could have compiled the newer NetworkManager by myself, but my skill level therefore is not that high ;)